# How to manually mangle names in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, gcc, linker

If I have a function in a .c like

```
void foo(int c, char v);
```

...in my .obj, this becomes a symbol named

```
_foo
```

...as per C name mangling rules. If I have a similar function in a .cpp file, this becomes something else entirely, as per the compiler-specific name mangling rules. msvc 12 will give us this:

```
?foo@@YAXHD@Z
```

If I have that function foo in the .cpp file and I want it to use C name mangling rules (assuming I can do without overloading), we can declare it as

```
extern "C" void foo(int c, char v);
```

...in which case, we're back to good old

```
_foo
```

...in the .obj symbol table.

My question is, is it possible to go the other way around? If I wanted to simulate C++ name mangling with a C function, this would be easy with gcc because gcc's name mangling rules only make use of identifier-friendly characters, thus the mangled name of foo becomes _ZN3fooEic, and we could easily write

```
void ZN3fooEic(int c, char v);
```

Back in Microsoft-compiler-land, I obviously can't create a function whose name is a completely invalid identifier called

```
void ?foo@@YAXHD@Z(int c, char v);
```

...but I'd still like that function to show up with that symbol name in the .obj symbol table.

Any ideas? I've looked through Visual C++'s supported pragmas, and I don't see anything useful.

Comment: @mustafagonul I'm not trying to demangle - I'm trying to mangle.

Comment: Even if you could do this, you'd have to somehow match the ABI.   You're barking up the wrong tree on this one.  Use extern "C" for this and accept the limitations.

Comment: @mustafagonul You're not quite understanding this. I know what the mangled and unmangled name is. I want to fake C++ name mangling in a C file.

Comment: @xaxxon The ABI is the easy bit. Visual C++ uses cdecl with C++ by default, with the exception that it adds a hidden first-parameter. This is basically how those old DirectX c-bindings worked back in the day. The tricky bit is getting the symbol names right.

Comment: Any assumptions that the name mangling would remain consistent going forward is also not a good assumption.  You're just asking people to hate you in a few years.

Comment: ... Not to even mention that Microsoft is known to change VSC++'s ABI from time to time. BTW, it's not exactly `cdecl`, but instead an extension of `cdecl`. I mean, a C++ ABI needs to handle name mangling, exceptions, virtual tables, and all of that funky stuff.

Comment: @xaxxon Of course not - it would be crazy to use something like this in production software. This is bizarro-stuff for a tool I'm building for myself.

Comment: @KemyLand IOW you and xaxxon are both 100% right that what I'm trying to do is completely gonzo, but it's still quite useful for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: "as per C name mangling rules" -- C does not have name mangling rules. Most C compilers us the **convention** of prepending an underscore to the name. I haven't looked recently, but twenty years ago, at least one compiler **appended** an underscore.

Comment: @PeteBecker You learn something new every day! I just checked the spec (c99 at least), and you're right - I can find no mention of the underscore in identifier linkage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using [`__identifier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzc8ytsz.aspx):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma warning(suppress: 4483)
extern "C" void __cdecl __identifier("?foo@@YAXHD@Z")(int c, char v)
{
    printf("%d %c\n", c, v);
}

void __cdecl foo(int, char);

int main()
{
    foo(10, 'x');
}
```

Comment: Have you got any reason to believe this actually works?  
I just tried it, it only accepts C++ keywords, not arbitrary strings.

Comment: @TurkeyMan It works. The `#pragma warning(suppress: 4483)` is required.  If you omit that, you'll get `warning C4483: syntax error: expected C++ keyword`, which is an error by default.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis this is exactly what I was looking for. As inventive as KemyLand's approach is, I think I'm going to switch the accepted answer to this one (while up-voting both of these excellent answers, of course).

Comment: For reference, in GCC you can [use the `asm` keyword](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html) ... although recent GCC versions directly allow "overloaded" functions in C which use the normal C++ rules.

Comment: Also, this answer looks like C++ code? (`extern "C"` and no in-file identifier)

Answer (score 8):

You're right. That's not (directly) possible (note: never trust VSC++). However, there exists a nifty workaround if you really need this. First of all, in the C++ file...

```
extern "C" int proxy(int i, char c);

int foo(int i, char c)
{
    return proxy(i, c);
}
```

Then, in the C file...

```
int proxy(int i, char c)
{
    // Do whatever you wanna do here
}
```

Without having to type any mangled name at all, you are now able to call the `foo` function, which is actually just a wrapper around the C function `proxy`. This gives you the same effect as if `proxy` was actually `foo`, from C++'s point of view. The single penalty here is of course a quick 'n' dirty function call. If the ABI allows it, and the compiler is smart enough, this can be replaced with a single `JMP` x86 instruction.

Another way would be to write a function `foo` in C, and then use MinGW's `objcopy` in order to rename the symbol...

```
$ objcopy --redefine-sym "foo=?foo@@YAXHD@Z" foobar.obj
```

I'm not sure if that's possible just with VSC++ tools. It would be very unstable, unportable, and hacky anyways.

Comment: Its not quite what I wanted for a number of reasons having to do with function prologues, but it might be the only solution.

Comment: @TedMiddleton: See the edit. There's actually another solution.

Comment: Using objcopy in mingw actually sounds like a pretty good solution. Thanks!

Comment: Please see [James McNellis's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35876444/434413) for the proper approach in Visual C++ (which is much simpler). James is on the VC++ compiler team.

Answer (score 6):

You might get it to work using a .DEF file.
Define your function in your `foo.cpp`:

```
void foo(int c, char v) { ... }
```

Then pass a [def file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34c30xs1.aspx) to the linker, that looks like this:

```
LIBRARY mylib
EXPORTS
   ?foo@@YAXHD@Z=_foo
```

Disclaimer: untested, I might be missing some details.

Comment: I only have access to MSVC2008 at the moment, and this solution *does not work*. Basically the linker interprets the "@" in the def file as a special character, thus the resulting exported symbol is only "?foo". Maybe this has changed in a more recent version of the compiler.

Comment: I actually tried this too on MSVC2013, and it doesn't work - as you said, it truncates at the first '@' character. You'd think that it was because the linker was confusing the @ character with the ordinal field, but it isn't - when I have a symbol like "?foo@@YAXHD@Z=_foo @24", like you I get ?foo but it does still get the right ordinal, 24.